# putty: CTRL-D not working and CTRL-R became CTRL-SHIFT-R

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, putty

I use windows to connect to my linux servers and since some time CTRL-D (to exit a session) doesn't work anymore and CTRL-R (search a previous typed command) got re mapped to CTRL-SHIFT-R

This is extremely annoying, can someone help me fixing this?

Comment: I had the same issue, which led me to your question. I haven't researched this enough to give a full answer, but I found that switching PuTTY to full-screen mode resets the Ctrl-R function. Click the icon in the upper left corner, then select "Full Screen". To return to normal mode, Ctrl-Right-Click, then uncheck "Full Screen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reply of Sagebrush reminded me to this topic.

What proved to be the solution on my system was that at some point the program "TinyTake" became part of of the startup routine without me realizing.

TinyTake wants to use the CTRL-R and CTRL-D, so it apparently remaps CTRL-R to CTRL-Shift-R and does no remapping of CTRL-D. Regrettably both CTRL-commands did not result in showing/starting TinyTake.. so I sort of stumbled onto this.. Now I have removed this program from the startup sequence (since I rarely use it) and shut it down after I have used it.

This solved my personal mystery..